# R - Calculate trendline and extend it for 365 days automatically

Tags: r, function

I have daily data with logarithmic decreasing trend (around 30-days-data).
[image]

In excel I'm calculating these data's trendline and with that trendline equation, I'm projecting these values to 365-days data. Then find the sumation of these 365 days' values.

Is there any ways to automize that in R by writing a function or using any package ?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. But is it estimating the coefficient of a 30-day trend, then you can regress your data against a 30-day sequence, t<-seq(1,30), and then estimate the regression by $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 t^{-1} + \beta_2 x +\epsilon$

Comment: After I calculate the trend equation as shown in the picture, I would like to find all values with respect to that equation, by writing 31,32,33,...,364,365 into the 'x' and sum all these values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you want to estimate the coefficient of the logarithm of a time trend, and predict the variable 335 days ahead after this. Your variable is $Y$ and the time trend is given by t<-seq(1,30), estimate

> Y.lm<-lm(Y~log(t))
>
> Y.predict<-predict(Y.lm, nstep=335)

is this what you want to do?

EDIT:

You can re-estimate the regression every time you have a new datapoint, extract the coefficient (from the intercept and time trend) and run the loop again. # day number n.

> t <- seq(1,n)
>
> x.lm<-lm(x~log(t))
>
> beta_0<-coef(x.lm)[1]
>
> beta_1<-coef(x.lm)[2]
>
> y <- rep(0,n)
>
> for (i in 1:n){
>
> y[i]<-beta_0+beta_1*log(i)
> }

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your solution is correct, but I couldn't apply it to my problem. How should I assign the variable Y ? I'm reading my data with t <- scan("data.dat"). So that's my sequence, but what will be the predicted variable ?

Comment: Is data.dat your dataset? Then you can just scan and call it Y or X or whatever. Or just import it to your workspace. But t is a time trend, so it has to be a sequence, t<-seq(1,30). You are regressing your dependent variable against a time trend to find the relationship between them. The predicted variable will be your independent variable, which you are scanning in data.dat. Right?

Comment: I understand, thank you very much ! But I have, Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Comment: I just edited my answer, it's supposed to be predict(Y.lm...) did you try that? Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Thanks @fredrikhs, I tried it. One last question, when I printout the Y.predict, it only returns values till 30. How should I get all values until 365 ?

Comment: It doesn't seem like the function can predict any further ahead than the length of your data. But since you now know the function you can calculate it yourself, with e.g. y<-rep(0,365)                
for (i in 1:365){
y[i]<-0.0872-0.017*log(i)
}

Comment: Yes, but that's the problem, I want to automatize it, how should it compute the values with respect to the function. Because everyday there will be different set of numbers which requires exact same procedure

Comment: See my edit in the answer.